# ReCaptcha V2 is not preventing bot emails in my Ruby site?

Tags: recaptcha

I have successfully added a checkbox recaptcha to my forms, however the spam emails previously being sent out are still getting through. It is the same name but a different email every time. Sometimes its every few minutes, and other times there are hours between an email.

Here is the form:

```
<div class="col-lg-7">
    <form action="/passport_online/specials" method="post" class="contact-one__form">
        <input name="authenticity_token" value="<%= form_authenticity_token %>" type="hidden">
        <input name="url" value="<%= @special.url %>" type="hidden">
        <input name="agent" value="<%= params[:username] %>" type="hidden">
        <div class="row low-gutters">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" name="first" id="first" placeholder="First Name" required>
                </div><!-- /.input-group -->
            </div><!-- /.col-md-6 -->
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" name="last" id="last" placeholder="Last Name" required>
            </div><!-- /.input-group -->
        </div><!-- /.col-md-6 -->
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input name="email" type="text" id="email" required placeholder="Email Address">
            </div><!-- /.input-group -->
        </div><!-- /.col-md-6 -->
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input  name="phone_number" type="text" id="phone_number"  placeholder="Phone Number">
            </div><!-- /.input-group -->
        </div><!-- /.col-md-6 -->
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="input-group">
                <textarea name="message" id="message" placeholder="Write Message"></textarea>
            </div><!-- /.input-group -->
        </div><!-- /.col-md-12 -->
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="input-group">
                <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey='******************************'></div>
                    <br/>
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
                </div><!-- /.input-group -->
        </div><!-- /.col-md-12 -->
    </div><!-- /.row low-gutters -->
</form>
</div><!-- /.col-lg-7 -->
```

And the JS for it:

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=onloadCallback&render=explicit"
    async defer>
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var onloadCallback = function() {
        if (grecaptcha.getResponse(0) == '') {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    };
</script>
```